# Where can I find Activity class?

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have made a dialog.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     myDialog = new Dialog(this);
        ShowDialog();
    }
    public void ShowDialog(){
        nevershowagain = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        closedialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closedialog);
        myDialog = new Dialog(this);
        int width = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*0.90);
        int height = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels*0.90);
        myDialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
        myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_disclaimer);

        closedialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (nevershowagain.isChecked()) {
                    prefrencestring = "1";

                    dialogPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editprefrences = dialogPreferences.edit();
                    editprefrences.putString("showdialog", prefrencestring);
                    editprefrences.commit();
                }

                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialogPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
        String check = dialogPreferences.getString("showdialog", "");
        if (check.equals("1")) {
        } else {
            myDialog.show();
        }

    }
```

Now, I don't know what to put instead of context in getDefaultSharedPreferences... Any help?
Someone says that i need to put the class of the activity but I'm new and I don't know what does it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `getApplicationContext()`

That way you will get the default shared preferences of your application context.